# CENTOS - Bash script to initiate a file transfer from a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, tftp

I am trying to create a bash script to initiate a file transfer to another machine via tftp app. currently i would do this manually by running the command `./tftp "filename" tftp://ipaddress/filename.`

What i would like to do is have a bash script that looks at a folder e.g (filetransfer) for any files an initiates that same command. can someone please help? as i am a noob at bash scripting

so far i have tried the below

when running this is says that the filename is bad

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ./*
do
  ./tftp "$filename" tftp://ipaddress/"$filename"
done
```

also tried this

when running this one below it transfers everything on the directory below it.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/the/directory/*
for i in *
do
  ./tftp "$i" tftp://ipaddress/"$i"
done
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "some help". What specifically have you tried and what specific problem did you encounter? Please show your attempted code. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @kaylum thanky you for your feedback it has been updated with what i have tried so far.

Comment: And what problem(s) do you have with what you tried? Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, `filename`, respecitvely `i`, can also take the name of a subdirectory, since you are looping over all entries in the directory. If you want to restrict the transfer to plain files, do a

```
[[ -f $filename ]] && ./tftp "$filename" tftp://ipaddress/"$filename"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried the solution you have provided but still getting an error bad filename. from what i can see when i tested it in a manual manner is that, in the part where `tftp://ipaddress/"$filename"` the filename variable is put as the directory path of the file and not just the filename. is there a way that it puts just the filename for that section.

Comment: @Eizan : To get just the name of the file without the path,  you get this using `basename` by `bare_filename=$(basename "$filename")`.